# Perform calculation from a text code - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, math, eval

Hi I'm struggling trying to perform a calculation in Laravel 7.

I have a variable like `$val = '1000*2';` and I'm looking for a helper function or related to perform it.

`eval($val)` does not seem to function in a proper way. I just want a function that results in `2000`.

TIA

Comment: Calling `eval()` is a dangerous operation, particularly if the values are user-supplied. There are libraries available to parse and evaluate arithmetic. Eg: https://github.com/mossadal/math-parser

Comment: I guess that would help me bc I'll need execute even pow functions. Do you know how can I add it to my composer.json or maybe which is the `composer require` command I need to run?

Comment: @Vzqivan `composer require mossadal/math-parser`. (Tip: if there's a `composer.json` in a repository, it can be imported like this.)

Comment: Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to deal with multiplication, you could try something like this.

```
$val = '1000*2';

$parts = explode('*', $val);

$res = array_reduce($parts, function($carry, $item) {
   return $carry * $item; 
}, 1);

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not advise using eval() to perform calculations with values ​​passed by a user.

If you really want to receive the value at all costs, you can do something like this:

```
$val = "echo 1000 * 2;";
eval ($val);
```

Or

```
$val = eval("return 1000 * 2;");
echo $val;
```

You can find more information in the documentation.
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

Guys this library helped me https://github.com/mossadal/math-parser

```
$parser = new StdMathParser();
$AST = $parser->parse($val);
```

Then I could access it with `$AST->getValue()`.

Thank you!!